# .Models does not appear in using ProjectName."Models" in asp core2 empty application

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I'am starting on an empty template and following implemented stuffs on aspcore2 mvc template but when I tried to do using MyProject.Models the .Models does not appear only the .Controller

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Diagnostics;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Webeu.????

namespace Webeu.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by adding a new Model in Models folder. I guess that how it works(The Models folder must not be empty to do this).